# Finding a word within a PDF then returning 11 characters after that word?

Tags: regex, vb.net, pdf, itext, wildcard

I have my code that searches each PDF page of a PDF document that has the word `Data_ID`.

This is on every other page in this PDF document and the way it changes is like this:

```
data_id 400M549822

data_id 400M549233
```

ETC..

So right now my console is returning all the times it finds the string `data_id` but I also want it to return those characters after it...

This is what I have so far:

```vb
Imports Bytescout.PDFExtractor
Imports System.IO
Imports System.Text.RegularExpressions

Module Module1
    Class PageType
        Property Identifier As String
    End Class

    Sub Main()
        Dim direcory = "C:\Users\XBorja.RESURGENCE\Desktop\one main\"
        Dim pageTypes As New List(Of PageType)
        Dim ids = "data_id"
        Dim resultstring As String
        resultstring = Regex.Match(ids, "(?<=^.{1}).*(?=.{5}$)").Value

        Dim currentPageTypeName = "unknown"

        For Each inputfile As String In Directory.GetFiles(direcory)
            For i = 0 To ids.Length - 1
                pageTypes.Add(New PageType With {.Identifier = ids(i)})
            Next

            Dim extractor As New TextExtractor()
            extractor.LoadDocumentFromFile(inputfile)
            Dim pageCount = extractor.GetPageCount()

            For i = 0 To pageCount - 1
                '        ' Find the type of the current page
                '        ' If it is not present on the page, then the last one found will be used.
                For Each pt In pageTypes
                    Console.WriteLine(resultstring)
                Next
            Next
        Next
    End Sub
End Module
```

The `resultstring` is what I was trying to use with regex but it's only counting the positions within `data_id` and not the ones after it.

So how would I do this so that it returns the following 10 characters (excluding space) after the word `data_id` ??

Comment: **(?<=data_id\s)[0-9A-Za-z]{10}** try it.

Comment: I can't find any reference to iText in your code, why did you use that tag?

Comment: @lucas_7_94 would i use that for the regex.Match(ids, ) part? My problem is that when i dim ids as "data_id" my code only searches for that literal string of characters.... How do i dim it so that it searches for "data_id" along with the proceeding 11 characters after it?

Answer (score 0):

Return 11 characters include space before:

```vb
'Dim ids = "data_id 400M549822"
Dim ids = "data_id 400M549233"
Dim resultstring = Regex.Match(ids, "(?<=data_id)(\s\w{10})$").Value
Console.WriteLine(resultstring)
```

Output:

```
 400M549233
```

Some notes:

– `?<=` = positive look behind
– `\s` = one space
– `\w{10}` = 10 word characters include A->Z, a->z, 0->9, _

Comment: Here's the thing though, the numbers proceeding data_id are constantly changing and those are the unknowns i need to search for to have them returned back to me.  If i Dim my Data_ID as "data_id 400M549233" will it not just look for that specific string all the time?

Comment: Can you say more clearly? The above my program will just search only 11 characters, after the words `data_id` ...

Comment: Oh ok, because if i Dim Ids as "data_id 400m549233" wouldn't the code only search for "data_id 400m549233" ??  Example, in my PDF page, there's several Data_ID's followed by unknown 11 characters.  So there can be data_id 400m54962 or data_id 400Z45623 and so on. If i dim Ids as "data_id 400m549233" its only searching for that value and returning 400M549233. < that value changes and is unknown so thats why i need to search by Data_ID only and get the next unknown 11 characters

Comment: Assign (some datas like "data_id ...") to variable ids. Then use like above: `Dim resultstring = Regex.Match(ids, "(?<=data_id)(\s\w{10})$").Value`